# How to pass a classic asp session variable array to client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a Session variable  which is an array of integers, for example:

myArray{1,4,3,5,6,7,9,2,...n}

What I am trying to do is pass this in a session var <%=Session("myArray")%> to my clientside javascript.  I can do it if I take the session var and convert it to a string like this:

```
    var b = '<%=Session("myArray")%>';
    var bob = new Array();
    bob = b.split(',');
```

I am just wondering if there is a more direct way of passing the array possibly cutting out the need to convert it to a string before passing so I can just pass it as an array?

Thanks

Comment: I think things stored in the session are serialized, so it would be returned as a string. You could simplify your javascript code `var bob = '<%=Session("myArray")%>'.split(",");`

Comment: I liked this idea but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Pre classic ASP session store the full object as-is, only Request and Cookies values are stored as pure string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
var bob = [<%=Join(Session("myArray"), ", ")%>];
```

Comment: This worked great when passing in an array which saved me converting the array to a string.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could parse the integers into something that is already an array, so you bob array woul be like that:

```
var bob = [<%=GetIntegersString(Session("myArray"))%>];
```

when the page is served to the client it should look like this:

```
var bob = [1,4,3,5,6,7,9];
```

the function `GetIntegersString` is something you will need to implement

Answer (score 0):

JSON is Javascript's way of expressing a literal value, so you could convert your array to json, and then assign it directly:

```
var bob = '<%=array_to_json(Session("myArray"))%>';
```

http://www.json.org recommends some ASP utilities to convert data to json:

```
http://tforster.wik.is/ASP_Classic_Practices_For_The_21st_Century/JSON4ASP
http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/
http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/
```

Read more about JSON to know how to express any value as a literal in JS.